# Kafka: Node sent an invalid full fetch response with extra

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have an application which consumers messages from 4 kafka topics. For simplicity sake, let's call the topics: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Each new version of the application uses a new consumer group id (basically a docker image ID).

Today, I had a problem where a new version of the application launched with a new consumer group which connected to `a`,`b`,`d`, but not `c` topic. Looking in Kafka manager, the new consumer group had no entry for topic `c`.

I can see an error in the client error logs

```
Consumer clientId=indexer, groupId=650-c6ac848] Node 331 sent an invalid full fetch response with extra=(a-28, response=(c-28","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler","thread_name":"kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread
```

I suspect it may be an infrastructure / configuration issue, but I can't be certain. I'm a developer - and I'm not very familiar with Kafka, so I don't where to look. The application code changes were minimal and shouldn't have impacted consumer group setup.

The log message to me suggests something related to heartbeat, and topics `a` and `c` have had their wires crossed somehow.

server.properties..

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka1.dub1.cloud:9092
auto.create.topics.enable=false
broker.id=16
broker.rack=dub1-zone4
default.replication.factor=3
delete.topic.enable=true
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3
log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
num.partitions=30
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Looking at the source code isn't helpful to the uninitiated

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/b8a99be7847c61d7792689b71fda5b283f8340a8/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/FetchSessionHandler.java#L394

Any suggestions on how to further diagnose this problem would be great appreciated.

Comment: What is your kafka version? Also, how is the cluster set up, are the topics configured for HA?

Comment: confluent-kafka-2.11. HA - yes I believe there is a replication factor of 3.

Comment: confluent-kafka-2.11 1.0.2cp2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the topic `c` had No messages and that seems to be the reason for errors I saw.

Comment: What do you mean by "topic `c` had to messages"? Do you mean "two" instead of "to"? Why would having two messages in a topic cause issue?

Comment: @JoshLemer I think I meant to say no messages, but I can't remember tbh